# does the Google Crawler see the dynamic content on my page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, google-crawlers

I have been working on my company website for around 10 days to completely turn my webpages serves the content through $.ajax and build the content through jquery. Now i found out that google will not see my page contents as its generated through javascript. I have verified that in chrome, when i go to View Source, i can not see any html elements that i have created through Jquery.

How to make google to crawl these DIV's OR say HTML?

## Ex:

```
$('.wrapper').html("<div class=\'product\'> This is Product 1 </div>");
```

Does google crawl `.product` DIV?

Comment: Googlebot is generally smarter than "view source", and probably sees a lot of the dynamic content anyway, but hashbangs are still the recommended way to solve this.

Comment: so does that mean that product div is visible to google even if it is created in browser

Comment: Only google knows that, but they do claim that Googlebot can read javascript and in many cases load dynamic content, but I guess it depends on how it's done, and I'm assuming Googlebot doesn't understand everything, or that it somehow uses a headless browser to test stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Sign up on Google Webmaster Tools, they have tools that show you how the bot sees your page. But even if it sees that stuff, I wouldn't render important content like that if I were you. Not everybody uses JavaScript, not everybody uses Google, it's standard SEO logic.

Comment: perfect... i was just reading about the #! method.... i am going to implement that one and i will also test webmaster tools.